# Can't access email with digital signature in outlook addin?

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing a outlook addin, which access metadata of an email. But i have the problem, that the addin is not shown in the outlook web app, when i select an email with an digital signature. When I select the same email in the outlook rich client then iget the error, that the operation cannot be performed, because the permissions for the message are restricted.
I set up the permission in the addin manifest to "ReadWriteMailbox".

Can someone help me, how i can access an email with digital signature in the outlook addin?

Comment: I have modified my answer based on Microsoft team comment. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Add-ins overview listed [Mailbox items available to add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#mailbox-items-available-to-add-ins). The following is the quote from the document:

> Outlook does not activate add-ins if the current message item, in a compose or read form, is one of the following: 
>   Protected by Information Rights Management (IRM), in S/MIME format or encrypted in other ways for protection. A digitally signed message is an example since digital signing relies on one of these mechanisms.

To answer on your question ... you cannot access e-mail with digital signature from Outlook Office.js add-in.

*EDIT*:

Per Microsoft team comment, digitally sign messages are available to add-ons. I have verified with signed SMIME message, add-ons are active and functionality is fine. Waiting for documentation update.

Comment: To clarify, we support add-ins in SMIME _signed_ but not _encrypted_ messages. We are working to update our documentation regarding our support.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have edited the answer based on your comment, great news.