# Error on Outlook Add-In with encrypted mails

Tags: outlook, office365, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed an Outlook Add-In that represents an html page with some JavaScript.

When I try to open the Add-in reading/writing an encrypted mail on our company's tenant, an error message appears.

> "You cannot perform this action. Permission to this message is restricted"

The same Add-In works on my test tenant with encrypted mails.

I assume it's because of different Outlook versions (version 2002 on my business tenant vs version 2008 on my test tenant) or some special settings in the tenant.

This post [Can't access email with digital signature in outlook addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502571/cant-access-email-with-digital-signature-in-outlook-addin) Microsoft explained that SMIME signed emails are supported but encrypted are not. But the post is almost 3 years old and as I said, it works with my test tenant.

Comment: What platform are you using? Is this for Win32 or Mac? Also just to clarify, by encrypted emails are these IRM/SMIME or signed emails? If this is for Outlook Win32, add-ins on encrypted mails are only supported on builds >= 13229.10000, see here for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview#add-in-activation-on-items-protected-by-information-rights-management-irm

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, thank you for your response. We use Win32 and SMIME encrypted mails. Since we are using the Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel, we will update in July/August to Build 13127.21624, which is unfortunately slightly below 13229.10000. 

Though this is exactly the Build I am using on my private device and I can use the Add-In with encrypted mails.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook Win32, add-ins on encrypted mails are only supported on builds >= 13229.10000, see here for reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview#add-in-activation-on-items-protected-by-information-rights-management-irm